# What is the meaning of "te echo"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, cultura-de-masas

In episode 1 of [*extr@ en español*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_(franchise)), Lola is upset that Pablo is using her exercise bike. She yells at him:

> Si tocas mi bici... ¡Si tocas mi bici, te echo! ¡Te echo! ¿Me entiendes?

What is the meaning of "te echo" within the above context? The common translation is "I miss you", but this translation makes no sense.

Comment: Note that `Te echo` is not translated as `I miss you`, the correct translation for `I miss you` is "Te echo **de menos**"

Comment: For more on "Te echo de menos", see [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4559/12)... but that's not what Lola was saying.

Comment: Wow i am learning spanish and my name is echo so its so weird seeing it be used a bunch in so many different and confusing ways 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Echar" has a lot of meanings. This is the following:

> **[echar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=echar&o=h)**
>
> 4. tr. Hacer salir a alguien de algún lugar, apartarle con violencia, por desprecio, castigo, etc.

That is: 'I kick you out [of somewhere]'.

So the sentence '¡Si tocas mi bici, te echo! ¡Te echo!'  means 'If you touch my bike, **I will kick you out of here**!'.

Comment: The meaning of "te echo" could be "I'll kick you out"  but if Lola is Pablo's girl friend then it could also mean "I'll break out with you"

Comment: I am so sorry @angus but In Colombia it does. However you have to be careful because it is very different to say "Lola echó a su novio" and saying "Lola se echó a su novio". The first is "to break up with him" the second is "to engage in sexual activities" .

Comment: @DGaleano interesante lo que comentas. Mirando la [definición de "echar"](http://dle.rae.es/?w=echar&o=h) nos encontramos un total de ¡48 acepciones! Luego mil significados pueden ser posibles según la zona. Por curiosidad, miré en [Bogotalogo](http://bogotalogo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Echar) y no encontré algo idiomático propio de Colombia que describa el "cortar una relación".

Comment: Nunca miré siquiera el significado porque para mi es natural. Cuando era adolescente, me echaron, me hice echar y eché . Por aquí funciona exactamente como la acepción 5. "Me echaron del trabajo" o "Mi novia me echó". Suficiente ilustración. :-)

Comment: kick you out of where? Te echo de la casa, del jardín.

Comment: @Lambie sorry I don't understand what you mean with your comment. Could you clarify?

Comment: OK, te echo is I will kick you out, here. If you touch my bike, I'll kick you out. Simple present cannot be used here in English. It's just an odd thing to say without saying from where. We have no away of knowing de donde se echa la persona. Si tocas mi bici, te echo [de aqui].

Comment: @Lambie ah right, now I understand, thanks! I didn't know. I have edited my answer to improve this part. Feel free to [edit] further if it is still needed.

Comment: I tried to put in "I'll" but can't because on this site there is that stupid rule about more than 10 characters. Do you not see why simple present is wrong here? I'd be glad to explain it....

Comment: @Lambie the sentence OP provided is a first conditional, so the _will_ is necessary. However, I was surprised to learn that 'I kick you out' alone would be wrong. Would it be in any case? Regarding the 10 (in fact 6) characters rule, you can also add some hidden text like `<!--- bla bla bla -->` somewhere to reach the minimum.

Comment: fedorqui: The simple present in English is only used for *habitual* activities: "Every week, Little Johnny, I have to kick you out of my class for misbehaving". In Spanish, "Callete o te echo [de aqui] ahora mismo" has to be: "Shut up or I'll kick you out" or "Shut up or I'm kicking  you out." //Thanks for the tip on hidden text! :)

Answer (score 1):

"Echar" also means "to lash out at someone, to give somebody a preach". "un rapapolvo / una bronca" is then left out.

Comment: Give somebody a preach is not English. We say: I'll let you have it. To let someone have it is an idiom= to yell at you.