# Palabras que adquieren significado al colocarse junto a otras

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

A veces encuentro cosas curiosas sobre el lenguaje que me entran ganas de comentar aquí, y en ocasiones no encuentro la forma de plantearlo como una pregunta. Así que a ver cómo salgo con esta. :-)

El caso es que acabo de encontrar una cosa en el diccionario que me ha llamado mucho la atención. En la definición de la palabra *rendir* me encuentro esto:

> 7. tr. Junto con algunos nombres, toma la significación del que se le añade. *Rendir gracias, obsequios.*

Es decir, que hay casos en los que la palabra carece de significado, y simplemente toma el significado de la palabra que sigue. Así, *rendir gracias* sería *agradecer*, *rendir obsequios* sería *obsequiar*, etc. Por llamarlas de algún modo, llamaré "metapalabras" a estas palabras "vacías" que solo adquieren significado en combinación con otras. Igualmente, llamaré "metapalabra parcial" a aquella palabra que solo es "metapalabra" en una de sus acepciones, al tiempo que tiene otras acepciones como palabra normal. Una "metapalabra pura" sería aquella en la que todas sus acepciones son de tipo "metapalabra".

¿Están estudiadas las "metapalabras"? ¿Existe alguna "metapalabra pura"? ¿Existen otros casos "metapalabras parciales" además de "rendir"?

Comment: ¡Interesante!. adiciónale _rendir cuentas_. Ojalá encontremos otras.

Comment: Haciendo uso de algo que nos enseñaste ayer en la pregunta sobre "hay mas sustantivos masculinos o femeninos" busqué en el dirae _Junto con algunos nombres_ y hay [muchos resultados](http://dirae.es/palabras/?q=Junto+con+algunos+nombres) Toca empezar a analizarlos. "Pegar" y "echar" son algunos

Comment: +1. Aunque creo que "rendir" tiene el significado de "entregar/dar" y esos casos no son tan distintos a oros significados y no es del todo cierto que solo adquiere significado junto a otras. Pueden ayudar en la búsqueda de metapalabras preguntas antiguas tuyas como [¿Cuál es la palabra del español que puede desempeñar más funciones diferentes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18171/5481) o [Palabra más polivalente del español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17100/5481). Ahí tenemos otros ejemplos de plabras que pueden variar su significado dependiendo del comp. directo, por ejemplo.

Comment: *hacer las paces* entraría como palabras de ese tipo?

Comment: Los verbos auxiliares? Ej. _hacer ejercicio/ejercitar_, _voy a viajar/viajaré_

Comment: Valen palabras que sólo existen como parte de una expresión?

Comment: Así en general, el tema del que quería hablar son las palabras que, según se da a entender por la definición encontrada, adquieren significado dependiendo de la palabra que siga. DGaleano ha encontrado otras con definiciones parecidas, como "pegar" o "hacer". Lo que busco son respuestas que profundicen en este "territorio inexplorado", por lo que vale cualquier cosa que penséis que pueda encajar con este concepto de "metapalabra".

Answer (score 4):

Desde el punto de vista semántico, es decir, por su significación, las palabras se dividen en palabras de **clase cerrada** y palabras de **clase abierta**.

Las primeras son palabras funcionales o gramaticales que cuesta definir en el diccionario, salvo que se describa su función: artículos, pronombres, conjunciones, preposiciones. Cabe destacar que no existe posibilidad de añadir nuevos componentes a este tipo de palabras (de allí el nombre de "clase cerrada").

En cambio, las clases abiertas contienen las palabras más significativas del idioma: sustantivos, adjetivos, verbos, adverbios.

Resulta al menos curioso que los autores del DRAE hayan tenido que recurrir a una descripción de la función de un verbo significativo como "rendir" para definirlo. Existen muchas frases verbales donde se yuxtapone un verbo y un sustantivo para conceptualizar una acción que puede o no tener un verbo propio:

- rendir homenaje (= homenajear)
- rendir honores
- rendir pleitesía
- dar un beso (= besar)
- tomar conocimiento (= enterarse)

Me parece muy objetable la solución utilizada por los académicos para definir ese uso de "rendir", puesto que no está alineada con la mayoría de las definiciones. Sólo encontramos algo parecido en la definición de un verbo tan indefinible como el copulativo "ser":

> 1. copulat. U. para afirmar del sujeto lo que significa el atributo.

Ahora bien, existen, entre las palabras de clase abierta, algunas mucho más significativas que otras (lo cual, creo, no justifica que las definamos en función de las palabras que las acompañan).

Entre los verbos, se me ocurren:

- **tornar(se)**: tornar(se) viejo = avejentar(se)
- **volver(se)**: volver(se) inquieto = inquietar(se)

Entre los sustantivos:

- de un **modo** increíble = increíblemente

En definitiva, creo que existen palabras pobres en significado que se enriquecen por la cercanía de otras que les aportan mayor definición, pero eso no las convierte en palabras de clase cerrada.